# RxJava Timer Observable but wait to complete

Tags: rx-java

I have something like this:

```
return Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(integer -> captureList.getLatestCaptureCut()) #1
                .flatMap(vp::processVideo) #2
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())     
                .repeat()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Boolean aBoolean) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Basically what i want is the following:

- I need an observable to start, initially after 10seconds and then

  - it does #1 when completed then
  - it does #2 when completed then
  - it wait 2 sec and repeat eveything but the first 10s waits and should run forever.

I can't find a way for this to work. It simply repeats the process every 2 seconds without waiting for onNext to get called. Is this supposed to be this way?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're after. Do you want to: pause 10 seconds, run 1, run 2, wait 2 seconds, repeat?

Comment: yes. repeat everything but the first pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Observable.timer(10, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```